# Primeng changes made in library not reflecting in prod build of angular cli

Tags: angular-cli, primeng, primeng-datatable

We are using primeng in our angular project. We have made some custom changes in the library like templates in some of the components. one such example is below , where we have changed the emptyMessage property template in datatable.

```
<div [innerHTML]=\"dt.emptyMessage\"></div>
```

The issue we are facing now is , in development mode the changes are getting reflected but in prod build its not working.i.e vendor.bundle.js has changes made in prime ng library only in dev build (ng build --dev)  kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working :)

We should use production build command like below

```
ng build --no-aot
```